# How to transform an English Gmail imap date to a French date format

Tags: python, datetime, locale, strptime

I have to read Gmail's imap mail with a Python script with Django, and it works well, except for the date.

I grab the date to this format: `'2 Apr 2012 13:21:43'` and use `strptime`:

```
date = strptime(date, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

But I've got an error because my locale is `fr_FR` and in France `Apr` is not a valid month abbreviation, and I don't know the other month name used by Google. If I knew, it, I could make a mapping:

```
{'Apr':'avr.',...}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could use the correct locale? Can I use the timezone on my `strptime` to indicate the date is in an English format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US')
```

**Update**

Have a look at dateutil package as well http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/1.5
if you wouldn't change your location. It works with your sample when I set fr_FR locale.

```
from dateutil import parser
date = '2 Apr 2012 13:21:43'
date = parser.parse(date)
```

Comment: Yes may be it's work, but i don't want to change my local set, i used this gmail imap parser, on a django project, and i don't want to break some date job due to my locale change ...